# Multi processes read different part of a big binary file simultanously

Tags: concurrency, multiprocessing, system-design

I have a large binary file, and it is saved on a NFS share disk. In the cluster, I want multiple processes to simultaneously read this big file. Each process gets a file pointer, opens the big file and reads starting from the supplied pointer and read some size of bytes.

How do I design this project? As far as I concerned, it is similar to some concurrency databases. Is there any lightweight library or open-source projects related to my project? I use the `C++` language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a point to use a library.

You could use basic stuff. Open and reposition yourself in the file and then perform the read:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

or

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: Thank you! I have this question because I'm not sure if the read on multiple processes is related the file lock, etc. I consider the system is similar to the web http requests to the web server. Thus I think we should design a system like the web server, which can handle high concurrency accesses.

Answer (score 1):

nicolae: I agree :-)

mining: so far you haven't said anything about a need for interaction between your readers.

Consider a simple scenario.
Let's say you have your C++ program called "dostuff" which takes the following arguments:

```
--name     something to lable your output.
--offset   offset point, seek to here (default to zero).
--bytes    number of bytes to process.
inputfile  the file you want to read
```

The following would run your two processes in the background.

```
$ dostuff --name "proc1" --offset=0      --bytes=100 \\myserver\myshare\bigfile.dat &
$ dostuff --name "proc2" --offset=100    --bytes=100 \\myserver\myshare\bigfile.dat &
```

You can open a file handle within each process.
So long as the data access is read only why do you want to make it more complex?

**important:** I'm not saying it *shouldn't* be more complex, I'm suggesting you haven't yet shown a need for additional complexity.  And that complexity is going to come from a need for your readers to collaborate.  If they don't *need* to collaborate then you're pretty much done with your architecture - use the links Nicolae provided and good luck to you.

Comment: Thank you! There is no interaction between the readers. All the processes  read their own part according to the given pointer and the size to be read. I have this question because I'm not sure if the read on multiple processes is related the file lock, etc.

Comment: I consider the system is similar to the web http requests to the web server. Thus I think the system should be similar a web server, which can handle high concurrency accesses.